# Zsh – Right prompt shows italic well, but not left prompt

Tags: zsh, command-prompt, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

The following is fine:

```
RPROMPT=$'%{\x1b[3m%} $HISTCMD %{\x1b[0m%}'
```

However, no italic is shown on left prompt:

```
PROMPT='%{\x1b[3m%} $HISTCMD %{\x1b[0m%} %{$blue%}%T${PR_RST} %W ♋︎%{$purple%}%n${PR_RST}%{$gray%}@${PR_RST}%{$limegreen%}%m${PR_RST} %{$gray%}${PR_RST}☦︎ %{$magenta%}%~${PR_RST} $vcs_info_msg_0_$(virtualenv_info)
$ '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RPROMPT` is being set to an ANSI-C quoted string with `$'...'`, so escapes and backslashes are being translated to special characters.

The `PROMPT` is being set to a single-quoted string, `'...'`. Every character is being copied literally.

Change the `PROMPT` to an ANSI-C string: `PROMPT=$'...'`.